# Как хранить файлы пользователей?

Tags: mysql, php, сервер

Как лучше всего хранить файлы пользователей на сервере и информацию о них? Допустим, пользователю выделяется место на диске для его файлов (аля dropbox). Как хранить их и информацию о них (размер, тип, вес, кому принадлежит и так далее)

Comment: Хранить с какой целью? Как файлы будут заливаться на сервер?

Comment: Любые файлы с целью хранения в "облаке"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В соответствующей таблице `user_files`:

```
id - int, pk
storage - int, fk - опциональное разбиение по серверам-хранилищам
name - varchar(128)
path - varcha(255)
size - int или bigint в зависимости от максимального размера и единиц исчисления
user - int, fk
```

Опциональные таблицы:

`user_quotas`

```
id - int, pk, совпадает c user_id. Можно для ясности его и назвать user_id
quota - int/bigint - доступное пользователю место
```

`storage`

```
id - int, pk, номер сервера-хранилища
host - varchar(64) - адрес хоста, на котором валяются файлы
folder - varchar(128) - папка, в которой валяются файлы, по-хорошему этого быть не должно и на всех серверах должна быть единая структура
name - varchar(64) - имя для удобной навигации
```

Где-то еще по-хорошему надо кэшировать информацию о текущем занятом пользователем месте, чтобы не прогонять каждый раз сумму всех его текущих файлов, например `user_quotas` превратить в `user_file_meta` и добавить там столбец с этим значением.

В этой структуре каждый файл записывается в таблицу `user_files`, при сохранении каждого нового файла он отправляется на сервер-сателлит или в нужную папку, данные о нем, включая айдишник пользователя-владельца записываются в БД. Перед каждым сохранением надо проверять сколько пользователь занял места в текущий момент и превысит ли сумма этого значения с размером файла квоту, если превышает - прерывать сохранение. После каждого сохранения надо прогонять счетчик, обновляющий данные об использованном пользователем месте.

Отдельным вопросом стоит публичный или непубличный доступ. Вышеописанная схема предполагает публичный доступ и то, что после вытаскивания всей информации о файле на него можно дать ссылку, но если предполагаются приватные файлы, то их нужно прогонять через скрипт-обработчик на каждом сервере. В этом случае, конечно, в бд не нужно название папки, куда все скидывается на сервере, потому что пользователь по факту будет отправляться на этот проверяющий скрипт. Кроме скрипта можно еще генерировать временные симлинки и аналоги, но, объемы тестирования и возможные проблемы будут на порядок серьезнее.